# CodeIgniter Project with Cordova

Tags: php, codeigniter, cordova

I have developed a CodeIgniter app and now I would like to run it in native app using Cordova. As what I have found is that Cordova doesn't support running php script in html which is now a concern for me. May I know is there any other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

"As Cordova only uses static assets (HTML, CSS, JS) as main components to create a working app and doesn’t run server side scripts (.php) for example, simply you can create API endpoints for your website that return JSON data, then you can connect to these endpoints via AJAX calls from your JS file in the app so you get the JSON which you can parse it and print it to DOM."

Taken from https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-build-a-PhoneGap-Cordova-app-from-a-CodeIgniter-website-or-any-dynamic-website